# Why do tests for Django Websockets have to be written in pytest?

Tags: django, testing, websocket, pytest, django-channels

All tutorials and official documents point to using pytest for testing Django's websockets. My question is why Django's unittest framework cannot be used directly and when this might change?

Comment: If you under Django websockets you mean `channels`, then you can perfectly write tests using the `unittest` library only. _why Django's unittest framework cannot be used directly_ - because Django's unittest framework doesn't offer anything for websockets since it's not part of Django? _when this might change?_ - when someone adds a PR implementing the missing bits, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) is standard python module not related directly to Django as it only uses it.

You could test async functions with unittest but with much more boilerplate ( import asyncio etc)

As docs for channels state

> If you have normal Django views, you can continue to test those with
>   the standard Django test tools and client. You only need the async
>   setup for code that’s written as consumers.

This is reason channels use [pytest-asyncio](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-asyncio) and it would not change in a future